# Devise: multiple login pages... how to redirect validation failures to the appropriate page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I have my Rails4 app with Devise, and i have a normal login/register page, and then i have a login/register page in my checkout.

On the **checkout** signup/signin redirects where i need it if nothing fails validations. When validations fail on my checkout register or checkout login page it redirects to the default paths.

How can I make the validation failures show up on the checkout login/register page(s)?

In my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_filter :store_location

  private 

    def store_location
      # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
      return unless request.get? 
      if (request.path != "/account/sign_in" &&
          request.path != "/account/sign_up" &&
          request.path != "/account/password/new" &&
          request.path != "/account/password/edit" &&
          request.path != "/account/confirmation" &&
          request.path != "/account/sign_out" &&
          !request.fullpath.match("/account") && #for confirmable
          !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
        session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
      end
      #FOR CHECKOUT
      if request.path == "/checkout/sign_in"
        session[:previous_url] = "/checkout"
        #STORE LOGIN PATH
        session[:login_url] = request.fullpath
      end
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
    end

    ...

end
```

Here is my Registrations Overrides, where I am trying to direct to the proper login page using my session[:login_url].

This line does not work **respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)** but the location is properly being set with the session variable.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      #THIS DOES NOT WORK, EVEN THOUGH LOCATION IS SET PROPERLY
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

  private

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      session[:login_url] || new_user_registrations_path
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would add a url parameter like ?ret=yourpath. Then you can use the same login path and if that param is present return their otherwise the default. You can also do this by subclassing the Devise::SessionsController for your checkout login and overriding the method for failed authentication. I would provide links but I'm on my phone. It is available in the main README for devise.

Comment: I just updated with my registration controller code... which is close to working. I cannot get the **respond_with resource, location: url** working right when resource does not persist. I am storing the login page url in a session variable if on the checkout login page (Application Controller updated)

Comment: I believe if you `respond_with resource` and leave out the location it will be inserted automatically. Otherwise you could wrap in an if check. Also you may have to make sure you have your responds_to formats defined in the controller

Comment: Yea, I believe rails automatically will build the path with the object. I am trying to override that with the location... however, it does not seem to work. I've tried to research "Devise with multiple forms" but it seems like no one else has done this, which is suprising to me. For example, if you look at the comments here: http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/ it seems others have the same issue

Comment: It seems you should be able to also provide the location. I assume it fails though if persisting saves and the location always depends on the model. You could inline an if else or the whole statement in an if. I'm looking at this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: Maybe if you can post the logs you are seeing that would help